# subscribe to route to get observable and do something with it in one subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this following code which get an information from the route, initialize an observable and do something with this observable :

```
export class ThemesEditComponent implements OnInit {

  themeId: string;
  theme$: Observable<Theme>;
  theme: Theme;

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap
      .subscribe(
        (param: any) => {
          this.themeId = param.get('themeId');

          this.theme$ = this.sectionStoreService.themes
            .pipe(
              map(themes => themes.find(item => item._id === this.themeId))
            );

          this.theme$
            .subscribe(
              theme => {
                this.theme = theme;
            });

          this.setFormValue(this.theme);
      });
  }
```

Because I have two subscribes in this code, I am wondering if there is a proper way to write it. I tried to do that with a switchMap operator without success. I guess I don't have the good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mergeMap`. I suppose the `this.setFormValue` is not working right. Because it's fired before the `this.theme` is set. You can try this:

```
this.route.paramMap.pipe(
  map(param => param.get('themeId')),
  mergeMap(themeId => this.sectionStoreService.themes.pipe(
    map(themes => themes.find(item => item._id === themeId))
  )).subscribe(theme => this.setFormValue(theme))
)
```